# Is there a link to launch Google Scratchpad instead of pop-up?

Tags: google-drive, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I installed Google's [Scratchpad](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scratchpad/kjebfhglflhjjjiceimfkgicifkhjlnm?hl=en) extension in Chrome.

I'm wondering if there is a way to launch it within the main window. I hate the way it opens as a popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get to a full-page scratchpad using

`chrome-extension://kjebfhglflhjjjiceimfkgicifkhjlnm/index.html`

I have set it as a bookmark for easy access.

Answer (score 0):

I think the purpose and benefit of Scratchpad is that it exists as a popup outside of the normal browser.  It does not have an address because it is a part of the browser itself (by way of being an add-on).  But if you want to access it within a tab, you would just use [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com) since that is where Scratchpad is actually saving the notes.